# Three disk (possibly RAID) data recovery

Tags: hard-drive, raid, data-recovery

I have on my desk three 160 GB disks that were once part of an HP Proliant Windows 2003 Server. They may have been part of a RAID configuration of some sort. They may or may not be damaged in some way. When I interface them via USB, one of them shows up as a drive, but unformatted. The others show up as uninitialized disks in manager. An alternative explanation is that the two drives were simply not unused.

What's my first step?

I've recovered data off damaged drives before but never had anything to do with RAID configs. How can I even tell if any type of RAID was used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do software reconstruction of your RAID it is hard operation if you never do this before and if data stored on RAID is critical it's better to give HDDs to service.

One of the best RAID reconstructor which I used is a http://www.runtime.org/raid.htm
You can use this program to identify RAID type and other parameters such as stripe size and offset.

P.S. Remember always take a full dump of your HDDs and work only with dumps not with HDDs!

Comment: It appears to be working. I'll know in about 7 hours.

Comment: Nice going! It worked!